# Python split with regular expression to divide string

Tags: python, regex

I have a need to recover 2 results of a regular expression in Python: what is searched and all else.

For example, in:

```
"boofums",3,4
```

I'd like to find what is in the quotes and what isn't:

```
boofums
,3,4
```

What I have so far is:

```
bobbles = '"boofums",3,4'
pickles = re.split(r'\".*\"', bobbles)
morton = re.match(r'\".*\"', bobbles)
print(pickles[1])
print(morton[0])

,3,4
"boofums"
```

This seems to me insanely inefficient and not Python-esque. Is there a better way to do this? (Sorry for the "is there a better way" construct on StackOverflow, but... I need to do this better! )

...and if you can help me extract just what's in the quotes, something that I'd easily do in Perl or Ruby, all the better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably best off with [regex groupings](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping):

So for your example I'd use something like

```py
regex = re.compile("\"(.*)\"(.*)")
bobble_groups = regex.match(bobbles)
```

you can then use `bobble_groups.group(1)` to just get the quotation marks.
See [named groups](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups) if you don't want to depend on an index number.

Comment: WORKS PERFECTLY.

Answer (score 1):

```
a, b = re.match('"(.*)"(.*)', bobbles).groups()
```

Brackets determine groups that are "saved" to the match object